# Training in SSD Implementation in Keras halts after few iteration without any output or error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection, tensorflow-ssd

After few iterations of first epoch the training process halts without any output or error message. SSD implementation in Keras was used from https://github.com/rykov8/ssd_keras

```
    base_lr = 3e-4
#optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=base_lr)
optim = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=base_lr)
#optim = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=base_lr, momentum=0.9, decay=decay, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=optim,
              loss=MultiboxLoss(NUM_CLASSES+1, neg_pos_ratio=2.0).compute_loss)



nb_epoch = 10
history = model.fit_generator(gen.generate(True), gen.train_batches,
                              nb_epoch, verbose=1,
                              callbacks=None,
                              validation_data=gen.generate(False),
                              nb_val_samples=gen.val_batches,
                              nb_worker=1
                               )
```

The output of the program is as below:

```
    Epoch 1/10
/home/deepesh/Documents/ssd_traffic/ssd_utils.py:119: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  assigned_priors_wh)
2017-10-15 18:00:53.763886: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.54GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2017-10-15 18:01:02.602807: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.14GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2017-10-15 18:01:03.831092: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.17GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2017-10-15 18:01:03.831138: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.10GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2017-10-15 18:01:04.774444: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.26GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2017-10-15 18:01:05.897872: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.46GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2017-10-15 18:01:05.897923: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.94GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2017-10-15 18:01:09.133494: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.27GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2017-10-15 18:01:09.133541: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.15GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
2017-10-15 18:01:11.266114: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.13GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
13/14 [==========================>...] - ETA: 9s - loss: 2.9617
```

There is no output or error message after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough memory, things you can do to solve the problem:

- reduce the batch size
- reduce the size of the train data
- train your models in clouds (AMS, Google cloud and etc)
- use another GPU card with more memory
- or try CPU

Comment: I have train the model on AMS g2.8xlarge instance, however the problem is not solved. When I reduce the batch size to just 2, the problem is solved.